# (Google Data Studio) How to Display Percentage Label for Stacked Bar Chart (Workes as Tooltip Though)

Tags: looker-studio

You can see below a stacked bar chart I made in Google Data Studio.

[image: Original Outcome]

Let's interpret it and take for example line 1 - *Configurator-LCV Configurator*.

The three colors, blue, orange and yellow, represent three different statuses, *In-Flight*, *TBD* and *Stand By*. Each status has a number of values it shows up in the Data Base: *In-Flight* - 2, *TBD* - 1, *Stand By* - 1.

In total, all the statuses apear 4 times. This means In-FLight has 50%, TBD - 25% and Stand By - 25%. As it is also shown on the tooltip in the image.

If I turn on the labels for the bar chart, I only get the number of values (4, 1 and 1). If I try to transform the chart to display a Percentage of Total, it then shows me 400%, 100% and 100%.

But in the tooltip, when you mouse hover, the percentage value is OK.

Is there a way to get the value from the tooltip to be displayed as the label?

You can see in the image below the desired outcome.

[image: Desired Outcome]

---

IMG #1 - How the stacked bar chart is data field configured

[image]

IMG #2 - How the metric is configured

[image]

---

IMG #3 - If I use a Percentage of max Relative to corresponding data I get this outcome. This is how it should look, with the percentages showing also on the chart, without mouse hover needed. It's just that the values are off. The correct value is 52.63%, not 58.82.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I seem to be able to do as you are trying to do on one graph but not on another. Is your metric auto-aggregating?

Comment: Hi,
I posted 2 additional images (IMG #1 and IMG #2) showing how the bar chart and metric are configured. I don't know exactly, but I guess this shows that the metric is not auto-aggregating.

Comment: What options are given in the comparison calculation?

Comment: If it helps, I've recreated one I created before with the metric configured as count distinct, Percent (this changes automatically when I change the next box), Percent of total - Relative to corresponding data, None

Comment: Answer to "What options are given in the comparison calculation?" ::: Percentage of total, Difference from total, Percentage difference from total, Percentage of max, Difference from max and Percentage difference from max.

Comment: Answer to "If it helps, I've recreated one I created before with the metric configured as count distinct, Percent (this changes automatically when I change the next box), Percent of total - Relative to corresponding data, None".

It doesn't work correctly. Sure, the percentage values show on the bar chart without mouse hover, but all the values are at 3.03% which is not correct. The best I could find was IMG #3 (from above). But it is still off by some percentage points.

Comment: All very strange, my figures are fine. I guess if you can figure out how it gets to those numbers it may help.